# Registros duplicados en consulta

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema al realizar una consulta ya que se duplican los registros si se encuentran en una tabla externa.

Las tablas son:

**Personal**

| clave | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| EM00455 | PEREZ CORONA JUAN MANUEL |
| EM00574 | LOPEZ MERINO RICARDO |
| EM06544 | GUEVARA MENA LAURA |

**Incidencias**

| clave | fecha | tipo | folio | quincena |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EM00455 | 2024-01-02 | VACACIONES | VAC546 | 1ENERO |
| EM00574 | 2024-01-02 | VACACIONES | VAC441 | 1ENERO |
| EM00574 | 2024-01-03 | VACACIONES | VAC965 | 1ENERO |
| EM06544 | 2023-12-20 | INCAPACIDAD | INC874 | 2DICIEMBRE |

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
select 
p.clave
, nombre
, CAST(CASE WHEN 
(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(p.clave) WHERE  quincena='1ENERO' and tipo='VACACIONES') is NULL THEN 0 
ELSE 
(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(p.clave) WHERE  quincena='1ENERO' and tipo='VACACIONES') 
END AS varchar) AS Vacaciones
from
[dbo].[Personal] AS p left JOIN
[dbo].[Incidencias] AS i ON p.clave = i.clave
GROUP BY  p.clave, nombre, quincena, tipo
```

La idea es mostrar cada empleado con el número de incidencias por cada tipo si es que tiene por ejemplo VACACIONES, de lo contrario mostrar 0 en esa columna

Este es el resultado actual, si un empleado tiene un conteo de incidencias se duplica el registro, se agrega el correcto pero tambien un registro adicional con 0

| clave | nombre | Vacaciones |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EM00455 | PEREZ CORONA JUAN MANUEL | 0 |
| EM00455 | PEREZ CORONA JUAN MANUEL | 1 |
| EM00574 | LOPEZ MERINO RICARDO | 0 |
| EM00574 | LOPEZ MERINO RICARDO | 2 |
| EM06544 | GUEVARA MENA LAURA | 0 |

El objetivo es que solo aparezca un registro por empleado

| clave | nombre | Vacaciones |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EM00455 | PEREZ CORONA JUAN MANUEL | 1 |
| EM00574 | LOPEZ MERINO RICARDO | 2 |
| EM06544 | GUEVARA MENA LAURA | 0 |

Alguna sugerencia por favor

Comment: Hola. La consulta funciona de la manera esperada, [verifícalo en este fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fFu_7Tqz). Si en tu caso no funciona, dinos qué versión de SQL Server tienes, y modifica el fiddle, agregando un set de datos donde se reproduzca el resultado que dices. He puesto varios registros repetidos a propósito y las filas de muestran agrupadas correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta no parece tener el problema que mencionas. Para más detalles, ver [este fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fFu_7Tqz). Si en tu caso no funciona, entonces puede haber un problema con tus datos propiamente, en ese caso, deberás aportar un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable con un set de datos donde se reproduzca el problema mencionado.

Además de eso, no hay por qué escribir un código tan enrevesado, cuando puedes hacer una suma en un contexto de `CASE WHEN`. Sumarás únicamente cuando el criterio se cumpla.

La consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT 
  p.clave,
  p.nombre,
  SUM(CASE WHEN 
          quincena='1ENERO' and tipo='VACACIONES' 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
      END) AS Vacaciones
FROM Personal AS p 
  LEFT JOIN Incidencias AS i ON p.clave = i.clave 
  GROUP BY  p.clave, nombre, quincena, tipo;
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo completo:

```
CREATE TABLE Personal (
    clave VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Incidencias (
    clave VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
    fecha DATE,
    tipo VARCHAR (50),    
    folio VARCHAR (6),
    quincena VARCHAR (10)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO Personal VALUES
('EM00455','PEREZ CORONA JUAN MANUEL'),
('EM00574','LOPEZ MERINO RICARDO'),
('EM06544','GUEVARA MENA LAURA');
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO Incidencias VALUES
('EM00455','2024-01-02','VACACIONES','VAC546','1ENERO'),
('EM00455','2024-01-02','VACACIONES','VAC546','1ENERO'),
('EM00574','2024-01-02','VACACIONES','VAC441','1ENERO'),
('EM00574','2024-01-02','VACACIONES','VAC441','1ENERO'),
('EM00574','2024-01-03','VACACIONES','VAC965','1ENERO'),
('EM06544','2023-12-20','INCAPACIDAD','INC874','2DICIEMBRE');
```

```
6 rows affected
```

```
SELECT 
  p.clave,
  p.nombre,
  SUM(CASE WHEN quincena='1ENERO' and tipo='VACACIONES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Vacaciones
FROM Personal AS p 
  LEFT JOIN Incidencias AS i ON p.clave = i.clave 
  GROUP BY  p.clave, nombre, quincena, tipo;
```

| clave | nombre | Vacaciones |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EM00455 | PEREZ CORONA JUAN MANUEL | 2 |
| EM00574 | LOPEZ MERINO RICARDO | 3 |
| EM06544 | GUEVARA MENA LAURA | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ujUJ5LOL)